# Preventing packages imported within my package from being imported

Tags: python, import, module, package, git-submodules

I know the title is a little confusing, so I made an example package that illustrates exactly what I mean. The package structure is:

```
pkg/
    __init__.py
    test.py
```

In **init**.py:

```
from test import func
```

in test.py:

```
import numpy as np

def func(x):
    return np.asarray(x)
```

Then, when I import my package, pkg.func() works exactly as expected

```
>>> import pkg
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> pkg.func(x)
array([1,2,3])
```

However, numpy is also imported as pkg.test.np, even though it wasn't specified in the **init**.py file!

```
>>> pkg.test.np
<module 'numpy' from '/Applications/Anaconda....'>
>>> pkg.test.np.array([1,2,3])
array([1,2,3])
```

Is this a good thing? Is it necessary? I don't like it because it added unnecessary clutter to my packages. Is there a way to stop it?

Thanks

Comment: It is completely harmless and normal. Avoiding it, if possible, would be a pain and likely completely pointless.

Comment: If you want, you can `import numpy as _np`. It won't hide the variable, but it'll mark it as "not part of my public API" and prevent `from pkg.test import *` from grabbing it.